# Getting JSON data from API with PHP and curl

Tags: php, json, api, curl, get

There is an API page and I want to get the whole API data with the help of PHP+curl
For example the url is    **https://example.com/api** which  contains the following:

{"data": [{"information":{"username": "john","id": 15}]}

I want to have on my php result page: {"information":{"username": "john","id": 15}

using GET method.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/api');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

print_r($result);


curl_close($ch);

?>
```

and I get white page.Where is the error?

Comment: Do you have PHP installed and working? `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: yes AbraCadaver

Comment: is curl and the php-curl extension installed?